# Remove directory part from current directory in zsh

Tags: zsh, cd-command

Let's say I cd to `/usr/local/bin` but I want to change my pwd to `/usr/bin`, how can I do that with zsh? I know I can do things like `cd /a/b/` and then `cd b c` in order to change my pwd to `/a/b`, but I can't quite figure out how to do what I desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the flexible functionality of zsh's `cd`, there are at least three ways to do what you desire. You can either write `cd /usr/local /usr` or `cd local /` or `cd local/bin bin`. One can probably come up with more solutions.

`cd`'s syntax in zsh is `cd OLD NEW`. This command matches your `$PWD` with `OLD` and replaces any matching parts with `NEW`. You should keep in mind that `cd` works relative to your current directory, so if you write `cd /usr/local usr` while in `/usr/local/bin`, zsh will give you an error, because there is no such directory as `/usr/local/bin/usr/bin`. Always watch the slashes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [two-argument form of `cd`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/367531) to replace a substring of the current working directory. For example, to remove `/local`, you can use

```
cd /local ''
```

Since multiple slashes don't make any difference, you can also write this as `cd /local /` (results in `/usr//bin`, then the double slash is simplified to a single one) or `cd local /` (also results in `/usr//bin`).

Another approach is to use command line edition. With the default settings, type `cd $PWD` on the command line, then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>: the variable substitution is replaced by the variable's value, and you can edit it to your leisure. Under `setopt auto_cd`, you don't need to write `cd`  first. If your configuration causes <kbd>Tab</kbd> not to expand the variable, use whatever key invokes the zle function `expand-or-complete` rather than `complete-word`.